# PHPCS overrule PEAR rule with custom tags

Tags: php, pear, phpcs

I'm creating a custom rule config for our project and want to use the PEAR rule 'PEAR.Commenting.ClassComment'.
But this rule checks more then we need. Like @package and @category. Is there a way to override the protected $tags from the FileCommentSniff (extends ClassCommentSniff) so the rule will be executed but only will check the @description en @since and exclude all the other tags?

I've check the PHPCS documentation but i couldn't find any information. Maybe someone else did change this rule and can provide some information.
Checked the http://edorian.github.io/php-coding-standard-generator but it seems like you can't provide custom options for this rule.

Comment: I've fixed it for now. Just excluded the rule and created my own rule with the validations i want to add.

Comment: Hi, do not put answers in comments; instead, write a regulare answer and mark that as accepted. This helps to quickly find the solution